# the toggle button on my divi website is not clickable when I open the link in facebook browsers through my iPhone6

Tags: facebook, mobile, responsive, togglebutton

I used divi built a website, my website address is www.pawtrails.ie, it is responsive to mobile screens, but I found when I open the link through facebook social media in my mobilephone, the toggle button is not clickable anymore. It is clickable in google chrome browser.

What is the cause for this? And what should I do for this please? I tried other social media, such as Wechat, the toggle button has the same problem.
 [The toggle button is not working when opening in facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR2i4.jpg)

[The shop image is not displaying when opening in facebook as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EFSQ.jpg)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It's the facebook in-app browser.

Their browser sucks, and has major display issues for most wordpress sites. If you're on an android, you can set your phone to open links through another browser. But the iPhone app forces you to open links through facebook browser.

So far, I can't find a fix for this issue.

Comment: Hello, Nathan. I opened a ticket in divi, and it seems that it is the divi and facebook compatibility problems. Now if you update to the latest version of divi, the problem is fixed! Hope this helps anyone met this problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit to answer the question - sorry about that mods - noob error) There appear to be two possible issues. Firstly mixed content (http) on https enabled sites won't appear, so images etc. that have been hardcoded to "http://", perhaps from before a switch to SSL. Secondly for other issues, the Divi WP theme does crop up quite often and updating that theme seems to have fixed it for the OP when I check their site.

(Original message)
Wasn't sure if you were getting the replies in my conversation app. I replied on the post too: https://charlesr.co.uk/why-doesnt-my-site-display-properly-in-the-facebook-in-app-browser/#comment-9

Did you change something since yesterday, because it's working for me?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Hello, Charles. I didn’t change anything, the problem is that I found it works with some devices, like samsung. I am using iphone6, iphone5, Both of them doesn’t work. Which device are you using？ Thank you